# How to make a non-blocking PrinterJob pageDialog in Java?

Tags: java, swing

Below is code to create a simple window with a useless button in it and a PrintingJob that automatically opens a page dialog when the program starts:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class DummyCode {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JButton("TEST"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    pj.pageDialog(pj.defaultPage());
  }
}
```

Current behavior: The page dialog blocks user inputs to the rest of the application - it's not possible to click or move the application window.

Wanted behavior: The page dialog shall not block user inputs to the rest of the application - it shall be possible to click and move the application window.

From what I can see `pageDialog()` creates a `WPageDialog` which extends `Dialog` and is hardcoded to set modal=true, aka it blocks user input to other top-level windows when shown. I essentially want modal=false such that user input to other top-level windows are not blocked by the dialog, but this is not immediately modifiable.

*Running the pageDialog in it's own thread does not resolve the issue.*

Is there some nifty workaround for this to achieve the wanted behavior?

Comment: It's impressive that the dialog is modal, but it never has a top level JFrame/Window attached to it. Why do you want the dialog to be "non-blocking"?

Comment: "One of the biggest traps for smart engineers is optimizing something that shouldn’t exist." - Elon Musk

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: @matt Because of the nature of the application and the usage of it. I don't want to get into any details.

Comment: _I don't want to get into any details_ okay but then this site is the wrong place for you - it __requires__ that you add all details necessary to answer the question for the sake of future readers

Comment: I don't see how giving details to 'why I want the dialog to be "non-blocking"' are relevant for anything. I need it to be non-blocking, that is a part of the use case (I describe that very clearly in the description "Wanted behavior").

Comment: Did you check the [ServiceDialog](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/print/ServiceDialog.java) ? It doesn't look too hard to construct, and you might be able to change the modality before showing it?

Comment: hmm .. still don't get it: isn't the pageDialog just for getting user preferences for page layout (that's a short-time operation, users shouldn't do anything else hence modal is okay), once you have them you do the actual printing on a background thread which will not block the ui (again the _why_, could well be just me being dense, though ;)

Comment: @kleopatra It's a complex mission critical application where the user's ability to navigate any parts of it must not be obstructed, not even by short-time operations. That's just the nature of it.

Comment: @matt The ServiceDialog is also hardcoded such that modal=true. I assume it would give the same problem as e.g. PageDialog.

Comment: then how would they configure the printer? If that's not can't you just print using the defaults (without showing progress, or showing progress somewhere on statusbar)?

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how the ServiceDialog can be shown non-modally.

Comment: @kleopatra The purpose of the page dialog is to let the user set up a page format, and to output the page format. What happens after the page dialog e.g. printer configuration, preview, progression, etc., is handled already. It's only the creation of the page format that is in focus here. The page dialog is a built-in feature and therefor lucrative, but since it fails to meet the 'non-blocking' criteria a new solution or workaround needs to be found. matt may have found a workaround, else a custom made page dialog will have to suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of creating a ServiceDialog explicitly, which doesn't block the origin JFrame (or anything really).

```java
mport sun.print.ServiceDialog;

import javax.print.DocFlavor;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;

public class TestPrint {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JButton test = new JButton("TEST");
        test.addActionListener(evt -> System.out.println("action!"));

        frame.getContentPane().add(test, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        final GraphicsConfiguration gc =
            GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();
        PrintService service = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob().getPrintService();
        ServiceDialog log = new ServiceDialog(gc, 500, 500, service, DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PAGEABLE, new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet(), frame);
        log.setModal(false);
        log.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("waiting");
    }
}
```

Something that probably shouldn't be done. The example at the bottom starts a separate process with jshell running and creates the print dialog. The original gui stays responsive.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import java.awt.Dialog;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;
public class DummyCode {

    static void drain(Process proc) throws Exception{
        InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader( is, "UTF8");
        new Thread( ()->{
            char[] buffer = new char[512];
            try{
                int read = reader.read(buffer, 0, 512);
                while(read >= 0 ){
                    System.out.println( new String(buffer, 0, read ) );
                    read = reader.read(buffer, 0, 512);
                }            
            } catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        } ).start();     
    }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JButton test = new JButton("TEST");
    test.addActionListener(evt -> System.out.println("action!"));
    
    frame.getContentPane().add(test, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/jshell");
    
    drain(proc);
    
    OutputStream os = proc.getOutputStream();
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter( os, "UTF8" );
    writer.write( "import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;\n");
    writer.write( "PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();\n");
    writer.write( "pj.pageDialog(pj.defaultPage());\n");
    writer.flush();
    
  }
}
```

Comment: _Something probably shouldn't be done._ hehe, I agree. I thought about this approach as well - it's a good attempt! Technically this could probably solve my issue, but realistically I'm doubtful it can be used. I guess I'll play around with it and see how it goes.

Comment: Oh now I get it, good find! Silly me dismissed the ServiceDialog approach you mentioned in an earlier comment because I overlooked the 'setModal' method. I'll try it out, thanks